# Django 1.3 LANGUAGE_CODE doesn't correctly

Tags: django, django-settings

At first sorry for my English :).

LANGUAGE_CODE setting doesn't work correctly.

When I configured LANGUAGE_CODE="mn", but default language code is "en".

from django.utils.translation import get_language
print get_language()

### >>> en

then I tried to configure LANGUAGES setting

LANGUAGES = ( 
    ("mn": "Mongolia"), 
    ("en": "English"), 
)

### but still "en"

changed LANGUAGES setting

LANGUAGES = ( 
    ("mn": "Mongolia"), 
    ("en-us": "English"), 
)

### now it is "mn"

but want above settings

LANGUAGE_CODE = "mn"
LANGUAGES = ( 
    ("mn": "Mongolia"), 
    ("en": "English"), 
)

It doesn't work correctly. Is it BUG ? or something else?

I also tried creating "mn", "en" locale.

Hope help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, be sure to read this specific topic in the Django documentation:

How Django discovers language preference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference

We're not using Django 1.3 yet, but we are using Django with multiple languages.

The first item to check is to verify the `Accept-Language` HTTP header being sent by your browser. Use Fiddler or Charles Proxy or similar tool to verify. Sounds like your browser may be sending "en-us" as a language preference.

Answer (score 1):

In your settings file, make sure `USE_L10N` and `USE_I18N` are set to `True`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-i18n
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#use-l10n